# Exclude items with the same name

Tags: php

I wrote a script that based on the user's country_code downloaded matches the appropriate records (rewards) from the database. Everything works until there are two records with the same name and different countries field. I would like such duplicates based on user code to be mutually exclusive, but I can not achieve this effect for two days.

Let's say the user's country_code is "US"
There are two records matched for him

[description] = "offer 1"
[countries] = "US, DE"

[description] = "offer 1"
[countries] = "All"

I would like All not to be shown if the user's country_code is in the countries field. If it did not match the country_code, I would like the All offer to be displayed. In addition, all offers with the All flag that do not have their duplicates should be displayed for each country_code.

How can I achieve this?

```
<?php

    function getRewards($dbh) {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `description`, `countries` FROM `sample_table`");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }

    function checkCountry($data, $user) {
        $countries = explode(",", $data);
        if(in_array($user["country_code"], $countries) || in_array("All", $countries)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // for testing i get this value from database
    $user["country_code"] = "US";
    foreach(getRewards($dbh) as $reward) {
        if(checkCountry($reward["countries"], $user)) {
            echo $reward["description"];
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Change your code to filter our the records in your SQL query, and not as the foreach loop afterwards. You can also limit how many records return tom the DB

Comment: There is too much that is unclear. You need to create a few arrays for us to test on. Include on where your code does incorrect return.